# I am trying to compute the month, day and year. how would i go about it?

Tags: c++

This is what I have so far...

```
   // years.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
  //

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int mm, dd, yyyy;
cout << "What is your birthdate? " << endl;
cin >> mm, dd, yyyy;

    switch(mm)
{
case 1:
    cout << "January\n";
    break;
case 2:
    cout << "February\n";
    break;
case 3:
    cout << "March\n";
    break;
case 4:
    cout << "April\n";
    break;
case 5:
    cout << "May\n";
    break;
case 6:
    cout << "June\n";
    break;
case 7:
    cout << "July\n";
    break;
case 8:
    cout << "August\n";
    break;
case 9:
    cout << "September\n";
    break;
case 10:
    cout << "October\n";
    break;
case 11:
    cout << "November\n";
    break;
case 12:
    cout << "Dcember\n";
    break;
}
    switch (dd)
    {

    }

return 0;
  }
```

how do I get the day and year? It has to come out as Ex: January 4th, 2003
I am not sure how to get the day for each month and how to get the year.

Comment: The question was incorrectly marked with `C#` tag. Please double check your tags in the future to ensure your question ends up in the right place.

Comment: You can declare month names like this: `const char *monthNames[] = {"January", "February",...};` then access it as `monthNames[month-1]`. Or put it in a function to check the boundaries.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> mm, dd, yyyy;
```

is wrong and should be

```
cin >> mm >> dd >> yyyy;
```

The you can just print day and year with

```
cout << dd << "th, " << yyyy;
```

Comment: so where cout in the case is, I should just include "<< dd << "th, " << yyyy;"? or include another cout?

Comment: @AlexisOcampo ...What?

Comment: // years.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int mm, dd, yyyy;
 cout << "What is your birthdate? Enter 2 numbers for month and day, enter 4 numbers for year." << endl;
 cin >> mm >> dd >> yyyy;
 
  switch(mm)
 {
 case 1:
  cout << "January\n" << dd << "th, " << yyyy;
  break;    like this??

Comment: @AlexisOcampo Remove the \n, but yes, it can be done like this (or with a separate cout, you can choose what you like)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you are trying to print the input date in the format specified. I guess you can just cout the date on each case on month switch.
eg:

```
switch(mm)
{
case 1:
cout << "January " << dd << " th, " << yyyy;\n";
break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

cin >> mm, dd, yyyy;   is not doing what you expect it to do. It does not read data into mm, followed to dd, followed to yyyy. To achieve that, you need use >> instead of ",". Now, why the code compiles? Because , is a valid operator in C/C++. It simply executes it's operands and returns the result of the last one. In your case, it retuns yyyy - so you are reading your data into single variable yyyy.

Same thing with cout and "," there.

Comment: years.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int mm, dd, yyyy;
 cout << "What is your birthdate? Enter 2 numbers for month and day, enter 4 numbers for year." << endl;
 cin >> mm >> dd >> yyyy;
 
  switch(mm)
 {
 case 1:
  cout << "January\n" << dd << "th, " << yyyy;
     break;        something like this??

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to make your program look a little nicer you could do this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int mm, dd, yyyy;
     cout << "What is your birthdate? " << endl;
     cin >> mm;
     cout << "/"; 
     cin >> dd;
     cout << "/";
     cin >> yyyy;
}
```

or even just simply doing:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int mm, dd, yyyy;
     cout << "What is your birthdate?" << endl << endl;
     cout << "Month: ";
     cin >> mm;
     cout << endl << "Day: ";
     cin >> dd;
     cout << endl << "Year: ";
     cin << yyyy;

}
```

and then just continue on with your code.